# Changing width of a component dynamically in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

Currently I have a component that takes in my mock data from [store](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand). I am able to render each page with dynamic data with the help of my mockdata that is stored in store folder:

mockData.ts:

```
{
name: 'Triggerfish',
imageSrc: require('../resource/images/ClownTriggerfish.png'),
scientificName: 'Balistidae',
diet: 'Carnivores',
maxSize: '20-100cm',
family: [
  require('../resource/images/ClownTriggerfish.png'),
  require('../resource/images/RedtoothTriggertish.png'),
  require('../resource/images/OrangeLineTriggerfish.png'),
  require('../resource/images/PicassoTriggerfish.png'),
] 

},
  {
    name: 'Pufferfish',
    imageSrc: require('../resource/images/DogFacePuffer.png'),
    scientificName: 'Arothron',
    diet: 'Carnivores',
    maxSize: '10-120cm',
    family: [
      require('../resource/images/DogFacePuffer.png'),
      require('../resource/images/GuineafowlPuffer.png'),
      require('../resource/images/StarryPuffer.png'),
    ]
  },
```

I then have a separate component called BottomImages.js where I am loading the image data from the mockdata.ts. Here I manually set my column number.:

```
const ITEM_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.2;

const BottomImages: React.FC<FamilyCarouselProps> = ({ family }) => { 

const columns = 3;

  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState()
return(
    <FlatList
      numColumns={columns}
      data={family}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            itemWidth={(ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * 3)) / 3}
            image={item.image}
            itemIndex={item.id}
            activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
            onChangeActiveItemIndex={(index)=>{
              setActiveItemIndex(index)
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
);
}
```

And my ListItem component which shows the images is below:

```
const ListItem: React.FC = (props) => {
const [background, setBackground] = useState(true);  

return(
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setBackground(current => !current)} >
  <Animated.View
    style={{
      margin: 5,
    }}>
    <View onClick={() => setBackground(current => !current)}
     style={{borderWidth: background? 0:0,
        borderColor: '#000',}}>
    <Image
      style={{
        width: props.itemWidth,
        resizeMode: "contain",
        height: 200,
      }}
      source={props.image}></Image>
      </View>
  </Animated.View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
}
```

So now the problem is that for fishes with 3 images in my family array has a good layout where it all fits in one row, but for fishes that have more than 3, the [view gets messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qir4j.jpg) and they move to the next row:

I want it so that the column number changes along with the number of images that are there in the array, for example if my Triggerfish family array has 4 images, then it should change the column number to 4.

Comment: Not sure if you can modify a specific row's column with the FlatList component, you might have to create a Custom List component where you have control over individual rows.

Comment: @Mohaimin It's not the rows I want to change, its just the columns variable in my BottomImages.js that I want to change. It should basically show the number of images that are in my family array inside mockData.ts. Example my Triggerfish family array has 4 images so the column should be column =4. My Pufferfish family array has 3 images so the column should be column =3 and so on.

Comment: Right, but the column prop is set on the FlatList component, which in turns sets the column of all the rows of the Flatlist. So, if a fish has 4 family, you'd want that specific row to have 4 columns, correct?

Comment: Correct, I would also like to change the itemWidth that is there in the ListItem where I'm currently putting (ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * 3)) / 3, but I want to change it to (ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * column)) / column after I get the particular number from the array. Anyway that's possible?